# Copy Database From one Server to Another (SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, copy, sql-server-2016

I am Trying to Copy a database (all Pr and views and tables) From SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2016.

I Right clicked on my source DB and clicked on "Task" and "copy DB"
It takes me to Wizard and I just followed instructions but there are couple things that I want to check:
Data source is real time so I can not choose Detach and Attach Method.(I am going with "Use the SQL Management Object method" and I need to go online!)
Secondly I have chosen Drop any DB on The Destination Server with same name.............!

After Running it I get Error in Create Package Part and in message it says No Description Found.

Performing operation

- Add log for package (Success)
- Add task for transferring database objects (Success)
- Create package (Error)
  Messages
  No description found (Copy Database Wizard)
- Start SQL Server Agent Job (Stopped)
- Execute SQL Server Agent Job (Stopped)
  .

I have been doing research for 4 days but could not find any solid information and I will be really appreciate any help or thoughts!

Comment: are you trying to just restore the database or totally switch to new one

Comment: I am trying to restore the database to a new server

Comment: why can't use back up ,restore method..copy operation messages you gave are not much helpfull